# Wrapping Named Route Helpers for Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

So I have just come out of an intense religious argument with a colleague.

We have object model and routes.rb:

```
resources :orgs do
  resources :lists do
    resources :posts do
      resources :replies
    end
  end
end
```

All these relations are one-to-many i.e. a list will always belong to exactly 1 org, a post will always belong to exactly 1 list etc. We are very aware of the general aversion to multi-nested routes, but have consciously decided to go in this direction.

Unfortunately this means that when you want to link to editing a reply, you have to write:

`edit_org_list_post_reply_path( reply.post.list.org, reply.post.list, reply.list, reply )`

which feels very silly.

I want to be able to do something like:

`fast_path( action: :edit, model: reply, type: :path )`

and use the fact that reply only belongs to one post, which belongs to one list etc. to work out the rest. Something like:

```
def fast_path options
  action = options[:action]
  model = options[:model]
  path_or_url = options[:type]

  model_fields = {
    reply: [:org, :list, :post]
    post: [:org, :list],
    list: [:org]
  }[model.class.name]

  arguments = model_fields.map { |field| model.send(field) } + [model]
  named_route_name = model_fields.join("_") + "_" + path_or_url
  named_route_name = action + "_" + named_route_name if action

  send(named_route_name, arguments)
end
```

although I haven't verified that this works or is particularly nice code.

HOWEVER, my colleague has done something like this before, where he overwrote many named routes in the name of making them more pleasant to call. He claims that it lead to nothing but misery, despair and torment, and is fighting tooth and nail to keep such attempts out of our code this time round.

I am very happy to be wrong, so please let us know what you think!

Comment: `link_to "Edit reply", [:edit, reply.post.list.org, reply.post.list, reply.list, reply]` Maybe this will be more acceptable? I'm also not the fan of fast_path helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to overwrite the path helpers (and there are undoubtedly good reasons not to do so), you could instead add a method to the `Reply` model like so:

```
def path_args  
  [post.list.org, post.list, post, self]
end
```

and then just call: `edit_org_list_post_reply_path(*reply.path_args)`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [shallow nesting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting)?

```
resources :orgs, shallow: true do
  resources :lists, shallow: true do
    resources :posts, shallow: true do
      resources :replies
    end
  end
end
```

Then you will still get deep paths for all the collections, but shallow ones for all the members:

```
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+-------------------+
| Helper              | HTTP Verb | Path                                  | Controller#Action |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+-------------------+
| post_replies_path   | GET       | /posts/:post_id/replies(.:format)     | replies#index     |
|                     | POST      | /posts/:post_id/replies(.:format)     | replies#create    |
| new_post_reply_path | GET       | /posts/:post_id/replies/new(.:format) | replies#new       |
| edit_reply_path     | GET       | /replies/:id/edit(.:format)           | replies#edit      |
| reply_path          | GET       | /replies/:id(.:format)                | replies#show      |
|                     | PATCH     | /replies/:id(.:format)                | replies#update    |
|                     | PUT       | /replies/:id(.:format)                | replies#update    |
|                     | DELETE    | /replies/:id(.:format)                | replies#destroy   |
| list_posts_path     | GET       | /lists/:list_id/posts(.:format)       | posts#index       |
|                     | POST      | /lists/:list_id/posts(.:format)       | posts#create      |
| new_list_post_path  | GET       | /lists/:list_id/posts/new(.:format)   | posts#new         |
| edit_post_path      | GET       | /posts/:id/edit(.:format)             | posts#edit        |
| post_path           | GET       | /posts/:id(.:format)                  | posts#show        |
|                     | PATCH     | /posts/:id(.:format)                  | posts#update      |
|                     | PUT       | /posts/:id(.:format)                  | posts#update      |
|                     | DELETE    | /posts/:id(.:format)                  | posts#destroy     |
| org_lists_path      | GET       | /orgs/:org_id/lists(.:format)         | lists#index       |
|                     | POST      | /orgs/:org_id/lists(.:format)         | lists#create      |
| new_org_list_path   | GET       | /orgs/:org_id/lists/new(.:format)     | lists#new         |
| edit_list_path      | GET       | /lists/:id/edit(.:format)             | lists#edit        |
| list_path           | GET       | /lists/:id(.:format)                  | lists#show        |
|                     | PATCH     | /lists/:id(.:format)                  | lists#update      |
|                     | PUT       | /lists/:id(.:format)                  | lists#update      |
|                     | DELETE    | /lists/:id(.:format)                  | lists#destroy     |
| orgs_path           | GET       | /orgs(.:format)                       | orgs#index        |
|                     | POST      | /orgs(.:format)                       | orgs#create       |
| new_org_path        | GET       | /orgs/new(.:format)                   | orgs#new          |
| edit_org_path       | GET       | /orgs/:id/edit(.:format)              | orgs#edit         |
| org_path            | GET       | /orgs/:id(.:format)                   | orgs#show         |
|                     | PATCH     | /orgs/:id(.:format)                   | orgs#update       |
|                     | PUT       | /orgs/:id(.:format)                   | orgs#update       |
|                     | DELETE    | /orgs/:id(.:format)                   | orgs#destroy      |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+-------------------+
```